# Include column names in the results of an unpivot query

Tags: t-sql, unpivot

We have this UNPIVOT query.

```
SELECT Value
FROM (Your select statement) as x
UNPIVOT (Value FOR val IN (a, b, c, d)) as p
```

That produces results like this:

```
Value
value1
value2
value3
value4
```

How can we elaborate to include the column names?

```
Value     ColumnName
value1    a
value2    b
value3    c
value4    d
```

Comment: Select Value, vx from?

Comment: @downvoter Care to comment?

Answer (score -2):

Thank you to Giorgi. Add `val` to the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT Value, val
FROM (Your select statement) as x
UNPIVOT (Value FOR val IN (a, b, c, d)) as p
```